# how to import primeng components using gulpfile.js?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm not able to import primeng components using gulpfile.js but where as I can import other third party components.

I get Unknown source error. Please help.

Do I have to change the path in primeng.js ?

Layout.cshtml:

```
   <script src="js/primeui-ng-all.js"></script>
 <script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: {
            "angular2-jwt": "lib/angular2-jwt.js",
            "primeng": "lib/primeng.js"
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

GULPFILE.JS

```
gulp.task('copy:libs', ['clean'], function () {
   return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js',
    'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
    'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js.map',
    'node_modules/primeng/primeng.js',
    'node_modules/primeng/primeng.js.map',
])
.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libJsDest))
 });
```

component:

`import {DataTable, Column} from 'primeng/primeng';`

I have imported datatable, column and added to the directive and used in the componenen as below

```
   <div class="row">
                    <p-dataTable [value]="projects">
                        <p-column field="name" header="name"></p-column>
                        <p-column field="projectState" header="projectState"></p-column>
                    </p-dataTable>
   </div>
```

But I get the below error :

```
 Syntax error
  Evaluating http://localhost:2595/lib/primeng.js/primeng
  Error loading http://localhost:2595/app/boot.js
```

Comment: Can you show us more code? How do you import the component? What is ngprime. I can´t find it. Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: PrimeNG is http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

Comment: I have added Primeng and it's working fine now. But im not able to add any class to p-datatable or p-column!! Why is it so?  @CagatayCivici

Comment: What do you mean by any class? A style class? Can you post your code?

Comment: <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p-dataTable [value]="projects">
                        <p-column field="name" header="name" class="col-lg-1">                      </p-column>         
<p-column field="description" header="description" class="col-lg-2">                      </p-column>                    
                    </p-dataTable> 
  </div>
   </div>

Comment: As seen in the above comment, I applied a bootstrap class col-lg-1, col-lg-2  to the column, where as the styling is not applied to the column. Plz hlp.. @CagatayCivici

Comment: I don't see  col-lg-1,  col-lg-2 anywhere in the code? There is styleClass attribute for p-column

Comment: Thanks a ton Cagatay Civici. That's what I was looking for :)

One more query, Is there any attribute for fixed columns. Something similar to 
 https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html ?

Answer (score 0):

you must change the map to :
map: {
'primeng': 'lib/primeng'
}

and you must to change the gulp task to export all component.

I'm working to change this configuration to import only the components that you need.